# apprequest to show in the notification globe (desktop & mobile)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications

I'm trying to send an apprequest to an existing user (who logged to the app using facebook login and authorized the app) and have it shown in the facebook notification globe.
I also haven't managed to find much up to date information about this issue on the official docs and/or here, everything to do with this is a few years old.

I want the apprequest to be sent from the servers and not through the fb ui which ships with their sdks, and I managed to do so by issuing a POST request to:

`http://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/USER_ID/apprequests?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN`

with form data which includes the message field.
The request works well, and as a response I get:

```
{
  "request": REQUEST_ID,
  "to": [
    USER_ID
  ]
}
```

The problem is that those requests are only shown in the games center (https://www.facebook.com/games) and don't show in the notifications globe.

I have a game app which I test this on, and both the android, ios and canvas settings are set.

Any ideas on which requests get to be shown up in the globe and if there's anyway to force my requests to go there as well?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this happening for multiple users? Note that due to various settings, notifications might not appear in the global jewel. Have you tested this with a (clean) test user?

Comment: @Roemer I've tested it with several users, which are all regular users, not tests users.  Which settings affect whether or not a notification appears in the "jewl"? Thanks.